# Synchronize video to openGL animation

Tags: ios, ipad, video, opengl-es

I am trying to sync a video to an animation drawn using openGL on iPad, and there are two things I am not sure how to do:

1. Find the currently playing video frame.
2. Make sure the update of the video and update of the openGL drawing occurs at the exact same time, as even a slight sync issue may cause visual artifacts.

Comment: By what means are you playing video? Using a built-in closed video player view or controller, or are you pulling frames out one-by-one via AVFoundation and then pushing them off somewhere?

Comment: I am playing the video via MPMoviePlayerController. I can then use CurrentPlaybackTime multiplied with the framerate to get the frame number showing, but the problem is the video is playing back at a different framerate than my opengl renderer. Is there a way to sync the two, so that I can always ensure my opengl layer renders on top of each frame in the video, before the next video frame is rendered?

Comment: Render the video using OpenGL, that's the only way to be sure. Anything else will be a workarround.

Comment: Re the comment about rendering video as OpenGL textures, that is likely to be your best bet. An example that shows how to push video frames from a file into textures can be found at this blog post: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it will work but instead of using `MPMoviePlayerController` you could use an [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer) and use and [AVSynchronizedLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSynchronizedLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVSynchronizedLayer) to synchronize your OpenGL layer timing with the `AVPlayerLayer`'s one.

You could create the video player like this:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"your_url"];
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];

UIView *playerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
[playerLayer setFrame:[[playerView layer] bounds]];
```

Then create a `AVSynchronizedLayer` layer and sync it with the `playerLayer`:

```
AVSynchronizedLayer *syncLayer = [AVSynchronizedLayer synchronizedLayerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[syncLayer addSublayer:yourGlView.layer];

[playerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[playerView.layer addSublayer:syncLayer];

[self.view addSubview:playerView];
...
```